# Python - problema com o PIP (ou com módulos)

Tags: python, pip

Estou desenvolvendo um programa igual ao mal direta do word, contudo, que permite também nomear cada arquivo na pasta.

Eu instalei em meu PC (Windows 7) o Python 3.7 e, para desenvolver o programa precisei utilizar o módulo "**python-docx**".

Eu conseguia trabalhar normalmente com esse módulo, mas após ao atualizar o PIP para a versão 18 o módulo citado "**python-docx**" passou a não ser reconhecido.

Acredito que o problema seja na atualização do PIP.

Os senhores tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer?

Ou, há algum outro módulo que me permita trabalhar com arquivos docx?

Obrigado.

Comment: Seria o caso de você especificar mais a sua pergunta. *"Passou a não ser reconhecido"* é muito vago. Edite sua pergunta e coloque a mensagem de erro, o que acontece quando tenta instalar o python-docx novamente, conteúdo das pastas onde ele fica instalado, etc, todo tipo de informação que possa nos ajudar a descobrir o que está ocorrendo com você

Comment: Caro @nosklo, agradeço sua observação. Tentei ser claro. Queria poder manter e continuar esclarecer essa questão, porém o módulo "python-docx" voltou a ser reconhecido pelo Pycharm. Bem, não consigo verificar o que ocorreu, pois voltou a funcionar. Vou ficar de olho. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wilson, o ideal seria que você criasse um virtualEnv.

Pode ser que algum software do s.o utiliza o python e ele não permite que vc manipule os modulos com o pip (pq ele instala no geral)

Crie um Ambiente no VirtualEnv (https://fernandofreitasalves.com/tutorial-virtualenv-para-iniciantes-windows/)

E acredito que dentro dele vc instale os pacotes necessários para seu projeto!

Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado, Rafael Rotiroti.